# Making my code better in reading and in performance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a python django code and I want to make it better in reading and in performance as I want to add it to my side projects and I am new to python and django. Can someone please help me

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
from .models import Victims, Url

g = GeoIP2()

def Get_Ip(request):

    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    return ip

def Get_Country(request):
    ip = Get_Ip(request)
    country = g.country('31.13.75.36')

    return country

def Get_Browser(request):
    browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

    return browser

def save_vistor_data(request, slug):
    ip = Get_Ip(request)
    country = Get_Country(request)
    browser = Get_Browser(request)

    _url = Url()
    url = Url.objects.get(slug=slug)

    victim = Victims(_url=url, ip_address=ip, country=country, browser=browser)
    victim.save()

    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

Comment: This question could be better if you could explain to us why you think it's not good enough? Do you have any expectations for it or is it just a vague question?

Comment: Referring to your visitors as victims makes me not want any part of whatever you're doing.

Comment: no its just for fun

Comment: If your code is working and you are seeking to improve it, then your question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you ser i will add it there

Comment: @ChamsAgouni your question as is will be off-topic on Code Review, as you don't provide enough context. Please see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: You can use a class to group like functions even further if they all take in the same params: `ClassObject.get_ip`, `ClassObject.get_browser`, and `ClassObject.get_country`. Then you don't have to import the functions just the class. You can implement `__init__` to create an object out of it.

Comment: can you please answer with your idea please

Comment: You've a model called `Victims` !??   Mmmmm .....  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g = GeoIP2()
IP = '31.13.75.36'

def get_Ip(request):
    """Get IP.

    Notes:
        This function retrieves/gets IP's.

    Args:
        request:

    Returns:
        some object.

    Raises:
        ConnectionError.


    """
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    try:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    except Exception:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip


def get_country(request):
    """Get country.

    """

    ip = Get_Ip(request)
    country = g.country(IP)
    return country

def get_browser(request):
    """Get Browser

    Notes:
        What should we know about this function.
        That is not already obvious.

    Args:
        request (type)

    Raises:

    Returns:

    """
    browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    return browser

def save_vistor_data(request, slug):
    """Save visitor data to ...

    Notes:
        Where is the visitor data going?


    Args:
        request ():
        slug ():

    Returns:

    """
    ip = Get_Ip(request)
    country = Get_Country(request)
    browser = Get_Browser(request)

    _url = Url()
    url = Url.objects.get(slug=slug)

    victim = Victims(
        _url=url,
        ip_address=ip,
        country=country,
        browser=browser
    )

    victim.save()

    return HttpResponse('Done')
```